# firebase not defined in JavaScript html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
<html>
  <head> <meta name="" content=""> </head>
<body> 
  <input type="text" id="nameid" placeholder="name" />
  <button type="submit" onclick="send()">submit</button>
 
<!-- firebase library-->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-database.js"></script>


 <script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
function send(){
  firebase.database().ref('user').set({ 
    name: document.getElementById('nameid). value;});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error of firebase not defined plz help me out you can see the code . Even i am not getting the data in my firebase Realtime database .i have even created the database .

Comment: Did you check your networks tab? Does the Firebase dependencies and core package load?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install Firebase sdk

```
npm init
```

for package.json file

```
npm install --save firebase
```

for installing firebase

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ... // Your config values
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

It's recommended to move your firebase configuration to another file if possible.
for more information read [Firebase Javascript documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)